# How to validate against a definition within a schema?

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to have a single schema file with many definitions.

I then want to validate messages against different definitions *within* that schema.

Is there a way of doing this with a JSON Schema?

I'm trying two NodeJS validators to see which works best:
https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4
and https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema

Apologies if this is not logically possible - I'm new to JSON Schema.

Cross-posted to https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/issues/170 and https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema/issues/94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed in the API section.

`tv4.addSchema()` and `tv4.getSchema(...#subschema_id')`